# Access the state of my redux app using redux hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am migrating my component from a class component to a functional component using hooks. I need to access the states with `useSelector` by triggering an action when the state mounts. Below is what I have thus far. What am I doing wrong? Also when I log `users` to the console I get the whole initial state ie `{ isUpdated: false, users: {}};` instead of just `users`

reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
    isUpdated: false,
    users: {},
};

const generateUsersObject = array => array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    const { id } = item;
    obj[id] = item;
    return obj;
}, {});

export default (state = { ...initialState }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UPDATE_USERS_LIST: {
            return {
                ...state,
                users: generateUsersObject(dataSource),
            };
        }
        //...
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

action.js

```
export const updateUsersList = () => ({
    type: UPDATE_USERS_LIST,
});
```

the component hooks I am using

```
    const users = useSelector(state => state.users);    
    const isUpdated = useSelector(state => state.isUpdated);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        const { updateUsersList } = actions;
        dispatch(updateUsersList());
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

first, it will be easier to help if the index/store etc will be copied as well. (did u used thunk?)

second, your action miss "dispatch" magic word -

---

```
export const updateUsersList = () =>
      return (dispatch, getState) => dispatch({
       type: UPDATE_USERS_LIST
  });
```

---

it is highly suggested to wrap this code with { try } syntax and be able to catch an error if happened

third, and it might help with the console.log(users) error -

there is no need in { ... } at the reducer,

---

```
state = intialState
```

---

should be enough. this line it is just for the first run of the store.

and I don't understand where { dataSource } comes from.